# best tooltip to use with asp.net form?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css, jquery-plugins

I want to use tooltip to show input instructions when a user fills out a form. Which simple tooltip code/component/plugin I should use?

I just want to show tips when a textbox receives focus and, and I'd like to be able to have multiple instructions in tip.

Comment: This topic seems to be more of a debate.  You're asking for personal opinions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is by far the most flexible tooltip plugin for jQuery.

http://craigsworks.com/projects/simpletip/

Also make sure it doesn't have anything to do with ASP.NET. It's all done at client-side.

Answer (score 4):

Although not specific for .NET. I use qTip (jquery plugin) with all my projects.

http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/

Implementation is as simple as...

`$('a[title]').qtip();`

Answer (score 0):

[jQueryTools](http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/tooltip/form.html) looks good as well.